# Read Text File Line by Line up to a character in php

Tags: php

Suppose my text file contains

```
MY NAME IS BOB_1984
I AM INTERESTED IN_FOOTBALL
I LIVE IN HERE_INDIA
```

I need to read and publish this in php, line 2 and up to _

So it would be

```
I AM INTERESTED IN
```

please help me to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, sorry but you're mistaken. StackOverflow isn't a code-for-free service. Present us a problem and what you have tried, and we can show you where you went wrong/better way to solve it.

Comment: Please find a minute and take a [tour] of this site. Also read [mcve] so as to know what can you ask here.

Comment: `<?php
$lines = file("mytext.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$line = 2;
if(isset($lines[$line-1])) echo substr($lines[$line-1], strpos($lines[$line-1], "_") + 1);?>`

Comment: From that I only get the text after _ but I need text before _

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$split = explode('_', $lines[1]);
echo $split[0];
```

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Yeah, example was from earlier spec where everything was on one line. Have revised.